# Unexpected C code output

Tags: c, pointers

This is my c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

int x[] = {6,1,2,3,4,5};
int *p=0;
p =&x[0];


while(*p!='\0'){

    printf("%d",*p);
    p++;
}

return 0;


}
```

When run the output is 612345-448304448336

What are the digits after the minus sign and why is my code giving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `*p != '\0'`, which is the same as `*p != 0`, is never met because your array doesn't contain an element of value `0`, and thus you overrun the array bounds and step into *undefined behaviour*.

Instead, you should control the array range directly:

```
for (int const * p = x; p != x + sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]); ++p)  // or "p != x + 6"
{
    printf("%d", *p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You run the loop till you encounter a `\0` but your array was never `\0` terminated.

```
int x[] = {6,1,2,3,4,5};
```

creates an array which is not `\0` terminated. You will have to explicitly add a `\0` as the last element.

Since the array is not `\0` terminated the `while()` loops run until a random `\0` is encountered. Technically, this is **Undefined Behavior** because you are reading the contents of memory which is not allocated to your variable.

**Suggested Solution:**

```
int x[] = {6,1,2,3,4,5,0};

while(*p != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C are not Null Terminated. Which is why your loop goes beyond the end of your declared array. The digits follows 5 are just whatever happens to be in that memory space. If there hadn't been a null character following your allocation of the array the loop would have continued running until it made a SegFault.

Comment: `char` arrays are null-terminated.

Comment: @NiklasB.  Only if you specifically null terminate them by declaring them with "contents" or add a \0 to the end. If you declare char[10] there is no guarantee that char[9] or char[10] are null characters.
Replace int x[] with char x[] and you'll see.

Comment: @Niklas B.: No, *strings* are.

Comment: @RussS: Sorry, yes, I meant `char[]` literals (strings).